# Enumerate going to left side (out of page writing place) after adding package

Tags: enumerate

I am having problems with enumerate, using the following code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[\textbf{Class A:}] High quality clean P-waves;
    \item[\textbf{Class B:}] Complete noise and absent P-waves. This included P-waves with \textit{no resemblance} to normal P-wave morphology, either due to motion artefacts, severe baseline wander, muscular activation interference, or simply by the absence of a P-wave;
    \item[\textbf{Class C:}] Unreliable, noise-distorted P-waves. This included P-waves that had \textit{some resemblance} to normal P-wave morphology.
\end{enumerate}
```

At the beginning this worked fine, and the enumerate was aligned with the remaining text, as I wanted:
[image]

However, after adding `\usepackage{enumitem}` to the preamble (I need it for a table), the enumerate items go to the left:
[image]

This only happens to \item's where I adjust the bullet point. In numered items, for instance, nothing changed.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code? B.t.w., your image shows no bullet.

Comment: Given that I am using my college's template, I can't, my apologies. In the example I showed, I changed the bullet into text (class A, class B, etc). In cases where I use real bullets or numbers, everything is okay

Comment: Anyway, there are no bullets in an `enumerate` environment. I must say that completing your code, the item labels flow into the margin, whether `enumitem` is loaded or not. So there's probably something in the preamble of your template. Which document class does it use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would use `description` list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[Class A:] High quality clean P-waves;
    \item[Class B:] Complete noise and absent P-waves. This included P-waves with \textit{no resemblance} to normal P-wave morphology, either due to motion artefacts, severe baseline wander, muscular activation interference, or simply by the absence of a P-wave;
    \item[Class C:] Unreliable, noise-distorted P-waves. This included P-waves that had \textit{some resemblance} to normal P-wave morphology.
\end{description}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent and P-wave quality was manually annotated and double-checked. Following the tool’s methodology, P-waves were classified into three distinct classes (Figure 4.1):
\begin{enumerate}[label=Class \Alph*: , font=\bfseries, wide=0pt, leftmargin=\widthof{\textbf{Class B:\hspace*{\labelsep}}}%
]
\item High quality clean P-waves;
\item Complete noise and absent P-waves. This included P-waves with \textit{no resemblance} to normal P-wave morphology, either due to motion artefacts, severe baseline wander, muscular activation interference, or simply by the absence of a P-wave;
\item Unreliable, noise-distorted P-waves. This included P-waves that had \textit{some resemblance} to normal P-wave morphology.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]